# Contiki powertrace with CC2538

Tags: cortex-m, contiki

I am using openmote (CC2538) on Contiki. I wish to use powertrace app with this platform, but when I run the program all readings are always 0. However, when I run it with tmote sky, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that the file `<contiki_root>/platform/<you_platform>/contiki-conf.h` contains

`#define ENERGEST_CONF_ON 1`